# How to set a conditional break point when a instruction is dealing with an address on a specific range?

Tags: assembly, exploit, ollydbg

I am doing some exploiting exercises, and I see my current exe is storing information in a specific address range.

Apparently the information stored seems to be encoded, so I need to debug the procedure that stores that information.

As the exe file contents loads of code I would like to set a conditional break point when any of the registers is set to an address in the range to analyse.

How can I get this done with OllyDbg or Immunity Debugger?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven`t yet used Immunity, but for ODBG the recipe is as follows:

1. Open Memory Map (Alt + M)
2. Select the proper address range
3. Set Break-On-Access (F2 or context menu)